# How to correctly alert my variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pretty decent understanding of Jquery but decided to dig in inside JavaScript because I have no understanding of "raw" JavaScript. 
So here's my problem: on document load my function executes fine and alerts: **'Hi my name is John'** but on button click it alert's just :**'Hi my name is'**. My question is why is this happening and how can I solve it? 
I know that I can FIX IT by putting my variable INSIDE my function, but is there a way to call my FIRST variable declared outside my function **(variable just after script type)**?

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6nuCx/)

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

//If I try to call this variable WILL NOT WORK:(

var name ='John'; <--SO HOW CAN I CALL THIS VARIABLE TO MY CLICK FUNCTION?--> 

function displayName(name)
{
//If I put my variable like this WILL WORK fine...
//var name ='John';
alert('Hi I am '+name);

}

//This function works on document load
//displayName(name);
</script>
</head>
<body>

<!--This doesn't work well if variable is OUTSIDE my function:(-->
<button type="button" onclick="displayName(name)">Display Name</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your code is actually fine, you've just chosen an unfortunate name for a global: `name`. If you change it to something else (like `foo`), it works: http://jsfiddle.net/6nuCx/1/

The *reason* for that is a bit obscure. Global variables become properties of the `window` object. But the `window` object already has a property called `name`, which is the *name* of the window. I'm very surprised to find that your code didn't work, because I would have expected your code to overwrite the window's name. But apparently not. (This is a **great** example of why it's best to *avoid global variables*.) Anyway, choosing a *different* variable name, one that doesn't conflict with the existing `name` property, sorts it out.

But you did something in your code that may be non-obvious, so let's dig into it a bit more deeply (here I'm using the `foo` version to avoid confusion):

```
// Here, you're defining a global variable called `foo`
var foo ='John';

// Here you have a global function, `displayName`, which accepts an
// *argument* named `foo`
function displayName(foo)
{
    // Here, within the function, the symbol `foo` refers to the
    // *argument*, not to the global. The global is *hidden* by
    // the argument (this is called "shadowing" -- the local
    // "shadows" the global).
    alert('Hi I am '+foo);
}
```

and in your HTML:

```
<!-- Here, `foo` refers to the global variable -->
<button type="button" onclick="displayName(foo)">Display Name</button>
```

It might be clearer if we change the name of that argument:

```
var foo ='John';

function displayName(f)
{
    alert('Hi I am '+f);
}
```

and the HTML is unchanged:

```
<!-- Here, `foo` refers to the global variable -->
<button type="button" onclick="displayName(foo)">Display Name</button>
```

---

Above I said it was best to avoid global variables, and that your problem was a great example of why. So how do we do that? Well, mostly by avoiding DOM0 handlers (like the one in your `onclick`). Here's how you might recast your fiddle: [Live copy](http://jsfiddle.net/6nuCx/8/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button id="theButton" type="button">Display Name</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Start a "scoping function"
(function() {
    // Everything within this function is local to the function,
    // not global
    var name = 'John';

    function displayName(n)
    {
        alert('Hi I am ' + n);
    }

    // Instead of the onclick= in the markup, hook up here in
    // the code
    document.getElementById("theButton").onclick = function() {
        displayName(name);
    };
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note how we were free to use `name`, because we aren't creating or interacting with globals. Also note that I put the code *after* the button, because the code assumes the button already exists.

Better yet, use `addEventListener` or `attachEvent` to hook up the handler.

```
var btn = document.getElementById("theButton");
if (btn.addEventListener) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", handler, false);
}
else if (btn.attachEvent) {
    btn.attachEvent("onclick", handler);
}
else {
    // Punt!
    btn.onclick = handler;
}

function handler() {
    display(name);
}
```

As you can see, we have to handle both, because older versions of IE (or newer ones in "compatibility mode") don't have `addEventListener`. Which is one reason for using libraries like jQuery, but I understand you're trying to expand your understanding without one, and for good reason. Best on that!

---

And finally, you asked:

> I know that I can FIX IT by putting my variable INSIDE my function, but is there a way to call my FIRST variable declared outside my function (variable just after script type)?

None of the above answers that. :-) The answer is: Yes, you can just refer to it directly, by removing the argument that shadowed the global: [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/6nuCx/10/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var foo ='John';

// Note: No argument declared
function displayName()
{
    // Because the argument doesn't shadow it, we can refer
    // to foo, because foo is declared in an *enclosing
    // context*
    alert('Hi I am '+foo);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Note we don't pass any argument ------v -->
<button type="button" onclick="displayName()">Display Name</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is good! The other thing though was that the OP couldn't access the global variable because it was shadowed by a local var. But since he passed the global var with the function call it should have worked anyway.

Comment: @DejoDekic: You're welcome! I added a note at the end answering a question in your question I didn't see at first. Best,

Answer (score 0):

Arhhh got beaten, was going to say using name is a bad choice:

http://jsfiddle.net/6nuCx/7/

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var name ='John'; 

function displayName()
{
alert('Hi I am '+name);

}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="displayName()">Display Name</button>
</body>
</html>
```